# Xcode UITextView Change textcolor of specified word

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, colors, uitextview

I would like to change the font color of a certain word inside a UITextView.

```
if([text1.text isEqualToString:@"value"]) {

}
```

That's what I have right now, and I want the word value to change font color, any ideas? Sorry if it's simple but I'm still learning ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, sorry.

from [UITextView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html)

> This class does not support multiple
>   styles for text. The font, color, and
>   text alignment attributes you specify
>   always apply to the entire contents of
>   the text view. To display more complex
>   styling in your application, you need
>   to use a UIWebView object and render
>   your content using HTML.